# SSIS Convert different Date String format to Date

Tags: excel, ssis, etl

I am trying to extract Data from Excel to SQLDB using SSIS ETL.

The Excel sheet contain a column called "Date".
The issue is that the date in this column come as string in different formats:

```
01.01.2016
1-Jan-2016
1-Jan-2016
01.01.2016
```

how to convert it in SSIS to one Date format

Comment: Are you just using the import / export wizard or have you written it from scratch? Sometimes the wizard will do things it thinks might be correct for odd reasons, have a look into the specifics of what the package is doing.

Comment: is 01.02.2016 = 1st Feb or 2nd Jan?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Derived Column task in data flow to cast the [date] column of your excel to date time datatype.